# Android: Compare two values doesn't work

Tags: android, if-statement, compare, rounding, decimalformat

at the moment i have a wierd problem... i can't make out where i did a mistake.

I have two pairs of values of the same type and i want to know if these are equal.
When i print the values in my Log the values are equal but my if statement doesn't work :/

The values are from type double, but i reduced the decimal to two digits with BigDecimal, like this...

```
double a = 50.7739202f;
BigDecimal bdA = new BigDecimal(a);
BigDecimal A = bdA.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

A and B are 50.77
C and D are 60.07

But he always goes to else

```
 if(A == B && C == D){
    ...
 }
 else{
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Have you tired using `Double.compare` to compare double values ?

Comment: use Double.compare method to compare double value's comparision

Answer (score 3):

To compare BigDecimals you should use their

```
compareTo()
```

Method and not "=="

```
a.compareTo(b);  // returns (-1 if a < b), (0 if a == b), (1 if a > b)
```

Additionaly you should avoid using the equals() method too because it compares the "scale" of the BigDecimals.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("2.00");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("2.0");
print(a.equals(b)); // false
```

Comment: Oh god, thank you very much i didn't now that. I'm quite new to java ^^

Comment: Do not forget to check the right answer if it contains the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests the object's reference, not for the values. use BigDecimal's [compareTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal))

```
if (A.compareTo(B) == 0 && C.compareTo(D) == 0) {

} else {

}
```

`compareTo` returns 0 when the values are equal

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `==` on two Objects, you are comparing their memory references.

`A == B` (with A and B both Objects) means `Is A's data stored at the same memory place as B's ?`